# Kitten’s left pupil more dilated

Tags: cats

I have this beautiful kitten, 3 month old, super active and super healthy. The last three days I noticed that his left pupil is always slightly more dilated (and actually his left eye is always a bit less open) than the right pupil.

I am sure he hurt somehow his face since I also noticed that the upper part of his mouth (internally) seems to have a bruise.

How much should I worry?

Comment: What did your vet tell you?

Comment: I observed this only one day after his vaccine last week. So I will go in the end of week again.

Comment: i do not think this can wait it is best if you get the kitten to the vet right now,this might be a sign of neurological damage.does the pupil contract if you shine a bright light on it?

Comment: By putting off a vet visit for something like this, you put the kitten's life in greater and greater jeopardy each day you delay. Go to the vet.

Comment: The vet only comes here once per week. Nevertheless she told me it is normal, and I should not worry. She will see him soon, in two days.